# show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(1/n) = -\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

How would you show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(1/n) = -\infty$ using the definition of what it means to diverge to $-\infty$.

This is what I'm thinking, but is it right?

Let m be a real number. Then there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_0<m$. Let $n < n_0$ then $\ln(1/n) < n < n_0 < m$. Hence, $\ln(1/n) \rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: Uh...if $m<0$ (which you want it to be, in this situation) then $n_0$ can't be in the natural numbers. That's just the first problem, the rest of it seems even messier.

Comment: You might start by noting that $\ln(1/n) = -\ln(n)$. So what you need to prove is that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \ln n = \infty$. If you do that (which will be less confusing), then your problem above follows.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M<0$ given we should find $N\in\mathbb N$:

$$ n\geq N\implies \ln \frac 1n< M$$

But $\ln \frac 1n< M\iff \ln n> -M\iff n> e^{-M}$

so it's enough to put $N:=\lfloor e^{-M}\rfloor+1$ .